# Changing fields to NOT NULL with NULL fields using migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I mistakenly created a table with fields which should have been NOT NULL.

I need to create a migration to change the fields from NULLABLE to NOT NULL, but some rows exist which are already NULL.

Hoe can I update these rows and change the fields?  I tried this:

```
  def change
    change_column :countries, :effective_date, :date, :null => false, :default => Time.now
    change_column :countries, :expiry_date, :date, :null => false, :default => Time.new(9999,12,31)
  end
```

But this failed with an error:

Mysql2::Error: Invalid use of NULL value: ALTER TABLE

Any ideas?  Needs to work on both mysql and sql server..

Comment: put :null => false after default and check if it is working.

Comment: still got the same error!

Comment: please see the link http://viget.com/extend/adding-a-not-null-column-to-an-existing-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First ensure there are no NULLs and then change the constraint.

Option 1:

```
Country.where(effective_date: nil).update_all(effective_date: Time.now)
Country.where(expiry_date: nil).update_all(expiry_date: Time.new(9999,12,31))
change_column :countries, :effective_date, :date, :null => false
change_column :countries, :expiry_date, :date, :null => false
```

Option 2:

```
change_column_null :countries, :effective_date, false, Time.now
change_column_null :countries, :expiry_date, false, Time.new(9999,12,31)
```

Comment: the first way is giving this error:  wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)C:in `update_all'.  I believe this is deprecated in rails 4.  The second way won't work with SQL server as I understand it.

Comment: I believe you're right about the first method being deprecated in rails 4. Why do you think 2nd way won't work? You can do in migrations everything you can do in rails. BTW I checked the documentation of change_column_null and it accepts an optional 4th argument, I updated the answer with it.

Comment: That change_column_null is not supported with the combination of JRuby and SQL Server. So the migrations actually failed when we ran them in that environment.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Have you tried the combination of 1 and 2? Updated the answer with it as option 1.

Comment: Btw, SQLServer adapter does implement the `change_column_null` method. What's the error message you're getting? http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/4.2.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SQLServer/SchemaStatements:change_column_null

Comment: locally we are using mysql but in other envs we use MSSQL use we use this gem:  activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter,  we don't use the sqlserver-adapter

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value for all NULL columns before adding the constraint, for example:

```
execute "UPDATE study_sites SET patients_recruited = 0 WHERE patients_recruited IS NULL"
change_column :study_sites, :patients_recruited, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```